# how to restrict Admin Page node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey guys im trying to make my admin page off limits to all the users except the one i have named john. What i have in my app.js file is

```
app.get('/admin',requireLogin, function(req, res){

  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Admin'});
  });

  function requireLogin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.username ==='john') {
      next();
    } else {    
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  };
```

The problem is that it just doesnt work, i can still access the page regardless of who it is i login as

Comment: And the problem is.. ?

Comment: edited it there, the problem is that i can still access the page without being the user john

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you just matching with username which is why the user "john" solely can login. You better try adding a `access_level` field in user schema in order to make it more flexible.

```
app.get('/admin',requireLogin, function(req, res){

  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Admin'});
  });
});

function requireLogin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.accesslevel ==='admin') {
      next();
    } else {    
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
};
```